# Getting Incorrect location with getLocation()

Tags: java, swing, components, label

```
public Textures()
{
    super(new GridBagLayout());
    layout.add(l1);
    layout.add(l2);
    add(layout);
    String[] T = filerw.fileRead2();
    if(T[0].equals("11"))
    {
        rect1.setLocation(layout.getComponent(1).getBounds().getLocation());
    }
    if(T[0].equals("12"))
    {
rect1.setLocation(layout.getComponent(2).getBounds().getLocation());
    }
    l1.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
    {
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0)
        {
            a = 11;
            filerw.fileWrite();
    rect1.setLocation(l1.getBounds().getLocation().x, l1.getBounds().getLocation().y);
        }
    });
    l2.addMouseListener(new MouseAdapter()
    {
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent arg0)
        {
            a = 12;
            filerw.fileWrite();
    rect1.setLocation(l2.getBounds().getLocation().x, l2.getBounds().getLocation().y);
    repaint();
        }
    });
```

I have tried many ways to ind the location of a component, and they all either get an error, turn up as zero, or the incorrect location. I have tried getX() and x, getBounds.getLocation, getLocation, getLocationOnScreen, layout.getComponent(1) or l1. How do I find the location of a component? I am tring to get a rectangle to surround the image, how do I accomplish the location?

Comment: If you don't get a decent answer soon, consider creating and posting an [sscce](http://sscce.org), a small compilable and runnable program that we can run and that will demonstrate your problem for us. Also, when posting code, please use consistent easy to read indentation. It's quite hard to understand someone else's code, so you don't want to make it harder for us by making your code indentation a random mess.

Comment: Also let's make sure that you understand that the location of a component is relative to its container. So the location of l2 will be relative to the layout container which holds it.

Comment: I would guess it is because the listener is added to a different component than you expect.  For something better than a guess, follow the advice of @HovercraftFullOfEels.

Comment: Layout locations are invalid until `validate()` or `pack()` is invoked . Also consider `setBorder()` on an enclosing component.

Comment: Trash, thank you! I didn't think of the setBorder() idea!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have answered this question by using a Border instead of a Rectangle. Thanks you trashgod!

If you are reading this to answer a questions, look at the comments above.